# SoundNote[ ] generates a different output for each audio channel

Tags: sound

When `SoundNote[]` is evaluated, I expect the audio both channels to be the same but they are different.

The code

```
a = Audio@Sound[SoundNote[]];
data = AudioData@a;
Periodogram[data, SampleRate -> QuantityMagnitude@AudioSampleRate@a]
```

yields

[image]

This shows two plots, where one corresponds to the right and other to the left channel.

What would be the reason behind making `SoundNote` generate a different output for each audio channel?

Comment: Stereo sound?  Low key on the left and high keys on the right on the piano?

Comment: interesting thing...